# woocommerce add line item meta to main order meta

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, hook-woocommerce

I have a created a simple gift wrapping plugin, which adds a gift wrap product to the user cart and when they enter a message it adds it as meta data to the line item, this is fine for the woocommerce system, but our backoffice needs this meta data to be on the order and not the line item, is there a way I can add the data to the order also?

```
function checkout_create_order_line_item($item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order)
{
    if (isset($values['_gift_wrap_message'])) {
        $item->add_meta_data(__('Your message', '_gift_wrap_message'), $values['_gift_wrap_message'], true);
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'checkout_create_order_line_item', 10, 4);
```

I have the above and and I have tried the folllowing,

```
function checkout_create_order_line_item($item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order)
{
    if (isset($values['_gift_wrap_message'])) {
        $item->add_meta_data(__('Your message', '_gift_wrap_message'), $values['_gift_wrap_message'], true);

       $order->update_meta_data('_gift_wrap_message', $values['_gift_wrap_message');
       $order->save();
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'checkout_create_order_line_item', 10, 4);
```

But this does not work. I would really apprieciate some guidance as to how to get `$values['_gift_wrap_message']` (or at least it's contents) into the order meta data

Comment: It's not clear what kind of backoffice system you have, but If you're sending data from WooCommerce to your external backoffice then you can loop through all the order items and store the custom meta in an array and then pass as order meta key as per your need.

Comment: The back office system requests the order from the wordpress rest api, there is not processing available the data needs to be in state ready to be read.

Answer (score 2):

For any dynamic order line meta, you should follow 3 steps

**1) Add custom meta fields on the checkout page from where customers can pass their message like this -**

```
    /**
     * Add a custom field to the checkout page
     */
     add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'custom_gift_wrap_message_field');
     function custom_gift_wrap_message_field($checkout)
     {
       echo '<div id="custom_gift_wrap_message_field"><h2>' . __('Gift Message') . '</h2>';
       woocommerce_form_field('_gift_wrap_message', array(
         'type' => 'text',
         'class' => array(
         'my-field-class form-row-wide'
        ),
        'label' => __('Custom Additional Field') ,
        'placeholder' => __('Write your message here...') ,
       ),
       $checkout->get_value('_gift_wrap_message'));
       echo '</div>';
   }
```

**2) Save your custom field data when placing an order from the checkout page**

```
   /**
   * Save your checkout page custom field value
   */
    add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta', 20, 2);
    function custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
        update_post_meta($order_id, '_gift_wrap_message', sanitize_text_field($_POST['_gift_wrap_message']) );
    }
```

**3) Fetch or display your custom field value**

```
    /**
    * You can get your gift message directly anywhere from $order_id like this - 
    */

    <?php echo get_post_meta( $order_id, '_gift_wrap_message', true ); ?>
```

**Example**:
Show custom fields value on the welcome page (after checkout page)

```
   /**
    * Display Custom Checkout Fields Data on Thankyou page
    */
    function gift_wrap_message_display_order_data( $order_id ){  ?>
        <table class="shop_table shop_table_responsive additional_info">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th><?php _e( 'Your Gift Message:' ); ?></th>
                    <td><?php echo get_post_meta( $order_id, '_gift_wrap_message', true ); ?></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    <?php }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'gift_wrap_message_display_order_data', 20 );
```

***Add the above code to your currently active theme functions.php***

Complete refrence URL is - https://www.cloudways.com/blog/how-to-edit-delete-fields-and-email-in-woocommerce-custom-checkout-fields/